# Failing to get session token with PFFacebookUtilsV4

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform

So right now I'm going through a Swift tutorial course on Udemy, but hit a roadblock.

As far as it goes Parse.com now uses v4 of Facebook's SDK and doesn't provide the same methods as before. I know I can revert back to the older version of the SDK, but I was hoping to get a fix for the current version.

This is the current snippet of the code, as of right now the current framework doesn't seem to have the session function anymore.

```
    var FBSession = PFFacebookUtils.session()

    var accessToken = FBSession.accessTokenData.accessToken

    let url = NSURL(string: "https://graph.facebook.com/me/picture?type=large&return_ssl_resources=1&access_token" + accessToken)

    let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)

    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(urlRequest, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: {
        response, data, error in

        let image = UIImage(data: data)

        self.profilePic.image = image

        var user = PFUser.currentUser()

        user["image"] = data

        user.saveInBackground()

    })
```

Hope to get some help on the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that I needed to get the AccessToken from the ViewController that initialised the login session using the following from the GraphAPI v4:

```
FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString
```

For some reason it returns nil in other ViewController classes, hope someone could help me know why.

For now made the access token a static variable but, hoping to find a better fix to the issue at hand.